# sed include preceding null

Tags: linux, sed, sh

What I have is a csv of customer appointments.  What I'm doing is dumping them from an SQL file, and then converting it into something that is usable by another program... specifically a calendar app, though that's beside point right now.  Customers are identified by number; not by name.

```
854,2018-08-19 08:30:00
2538546,2018-08-21 13:00:00
```

No problem, I want to replace the number with the name, so I pull the name by number, and run a sed command, like this...

```
sed -i -e "s/$custnum/$fullName/g" ~/Appointments/Appts.csv
```

But that creates a problem, because it turns the above csv into

```
John Doe,2018-08-19 08:30:00  #This is right
253John Doe6,2018-08-21 13:00:00  #This is totally not right
```

I'm thinking I need it to search/replace not just for $custnum, but specifically $custnum that is bounded by nothing (a null character?) and by a comma, so it doesn't replace matching characters in the middle of a number.  I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are no nulls here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt
854,2018-08-19 08:30:00
2538546,2018-08-21 13:00:00

$ custnum=854
$ fullName='John Doe'
$ sed "s/^$custnum,/$fullName,/g" ip.txt
John Doe,2018-08-19 08:30:00
2538546,2018-08-21 13:00:00
```

- `^` is a metacharacter to anchor the search to only start of line
- `,` after `custnum` would ensure that part of number is not matched
- in replacement section, add back the `,` after name
- as a good practice, double quote only the substitution portion and use single quotes for rest of the command: `sed 's/^'"$custnum"',/'"$fullName"',/g'`

Further reading: [GNU sed manual - Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions-Overview)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!